# How to format date in v-Calendar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vcalendar

I'am trying to get a proper output of date from the v-calendar. Now this looks like:

```
Fri Jul 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (utc summertime)
```

This should be 2020-07-28 etc.. I Can't find anything in the documentation that work, anyone know how to change output?

Code:

```
{{ date }}

<v-date-picker
    v-model="date"
    color="red"
    is-inline
    :available-dates='dates'
    :masks='{ input:["L", "YYYY-MM-DD"] }'
/>
```

Script for test:

```
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: "#dic",
        data: {
            date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        },
    });
</script>
```

Comment: where do you want it to be formatted in the script or in the input?

Comment: On the output, i want to update the date variable.

Comment: did you see this https://vcalendar.io/i18n.html#formatting-parsing-dates

Comment: Yes, but unclear how to implement.

Comment: try `<v-calendar  :masks='{ input:["L", "YYYY-MM-DD", "YYYY/MM/DD"] }' />`

Comment: Date is still: Fri Jul 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 ( etc....

Comment: where do you get this in the UI or you're printing it somewhere?

Comment: Updated the code, i echo it on html

Comment: could you create a codepen sample in order to debug it

Comment: https://codepen.io/sdgsdgsd/pen/gOPJXEJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a computed property called `formattedDate` based on `date` and use it and keep the `data` property :

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
  },

  computed: {
    formattedDate() {
      return moment(this.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src='https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js'></script>

<script src='https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/v-calendar'></script>
<div id='app'>
  {{formattedDate }}

  <v-date-picker v-model="date" color="red" is-inline />
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!